# How to send multiple cell data of a particular row out of multiple row if....radio button to that row is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In my jsp, I am using one form. Within that form one table is there and within that table rows are dynamically generated. In every row starting row is one radio button i.e. use can able to select only one radio button. After the table one submit button is there.

When I click on submit button, then all the row data is transferred.

What I want is, when user click on submit button only that row data should be submitted which have a checked radio button. One thing I don't want to use any AJAX. I want to simply use html, JavaScript, jquery concept to fulfill it.

I want to transfer that row cell data to one of my Spring controller having annotation configuration.

Answer (score 0):

set the value of radio button to the id of your rows

```
      if(document.getElementById('radio_but').checked) {

        // here u can get the value of ur row elements having id same as radio button val

         }
```

can u give ur code snippet so it can be understood clearly

Comment: <form action="..." method="post"><table><tr><td><input type="radio" value="radio"/></td><td><input type="hidden" value="${...}">${...}</td>...</tr>...</table></form> I want when i click on submit button only that row data is to be submited having checked radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :

## HTML Part

```
<table class="MyTable">
<tr><td><input type="radio" value="radio"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td><td>One</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" value="radio"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td><td>Two</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" value="radio"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td><td>Three</td></tr>
</table>
```

## JQuery Part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#save').click(function(){
        var CompleteCheckedRadioButtons=$('table.MyTable').find('tr').find('td:eq(0)').find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked');
        for(var i=0;i<CompleteCheckedRadioButtons.length;i++){
        var MySingleRow=$(CompleteCheckedRadioButtons[i]).parent('td').parent('tr');
        var textboxvalue=$(MySingleRow).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val();
        var htmlvalue=$(MySingleRow).find('td:eq(2)').html();
        }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could not place the input elements which are not supposed to be submitted in the form element.
The form element should only contain a submit button in your markup. 
when user click the radio button, create a [hidden] input element **dynamically** and insert it into the form element.
Hope it will be helpful.